# receinv bad json format from service

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, model-view-controller

I get the following: How to make it as a valid JSON?

```
{{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Kaizen",
  "living": {
    "city": "Sydney",
    "state": "NSW"
  },
  "Country": {
    "name": "Australia",
    "region": "APAC"
  }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a valid JSON except for the opening and closing bracket.
You can simply cut it out:

```
string jsonString = yourServerClient.GetData();

jsonString = jsonString.Trim();
jsonString = jsonString.Substring(1, jsonString.Length - 2);

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

However, I would recommend you to refuse using any incorrect or invalid data sources - it is the road to hell. 
You can never expect what they do next, and you definitely do not want to spend much of your time every time they change their service, and rewrite (and worsen) your code such that it now supports their incorrect format.